# Is there any mirroless full frame alternatives to Sony?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, full-frame, mirrorless

I am looking for a mirrorless camera, i would prefer it to be full frame and not made by Sony.

Every time i try to search for one, i am drawned by the counteless pages generated by Sony agressive marketing campain and inumerable recomendations and reviews.

I am looking for anything BUT Sony. In APS-C the Fuji X series would fit my needs, but they have no FF models as of yet.

So, are there, any FF mirroless other than Sony?

Comment: Why the boycott against Sony? Any prejudice only affects you.

Comment: So purely because of their marketing. Despite any positive reviews. And failure to find any alternatives. You refuse to use a Sony?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because speculation about future models is out of the site's scope. (See the site's [help center](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/130/should-we-allow-questions-about-unreleased-cameras).)

Comment: mattdm i edited out  "are there, or will be in the next year or so" but i don't think it was speculation AT ALL. companies often announce their products a year in advance, the exact price is a specualtion but not the FACT that it will be there.

Comment: Why are you basing everything on internet reviews? Have you gone to a shop and held one of the Sony Alpha 7 series in your hands? Why don't you rent one for a weekend?

Comment: @osullic Not everyone has that option. Where i am now in Africa, there are 3 general "electronic stores" with 10 new cameras, all entry level, between them. There are much beter used choice, older and cheaper items trickle down from richer european pastures. i handled a Nex3N, but no FF. Given its price, unless someone steals one from a passing tourist, it is not likely i will see one here. So, no i can't test it. I can wait till i go back to europe in a few months, or buy something else here. However, apart from reviews, i saw pics taken by Sony FF, they look worse than ones taken by a m4/3

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are. Full-frame mirrorless cameras are also offered by Leica. Check out the Leica M family, Leica SL and Leica Q (whose lens is not interchangeable). It's possible that when you see the price-tag, you will reject Leica as an option too.

Comment: yea, forgot about them, i know their price, i would get one if money was not an issue, though 5..... as this is a camera for walking around and as second body to my Eos 5D, i guess i will have to resign myself to an aps-c